# How do I have to configure Eclipse to show me only direct members of a type in an autocomplete proposal?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-jdt

I want to see only direct members - and not derived class members - in the default auto completion popup when I hit `Ctrl + Space`. What do I need to check / uncheck here to make this work?

Of course I tried a couple of configurations myself, but was not successful.

This is Eclipse Kepler with Android Development Tools 22, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the behavior of content assist by going to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist. The setting 'Hide proposals not visible in the invocation context' will determine which members are 'suggested'.

[image]

How this behaves is also determined by the access modifier of the member (private, protected, public).

For example with private members in the super class:

```
public class Animal {
    private int legs = 0;
    private int arms = 0;
}
```

The following is available when with content assist (ctrl+space):

[image]

Using protected :

```
public class Animal {
    protected int legs = 0;
    protected int arms = 0;
}
```

[image]